# How can I disable Tomcat caching completly?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, tomcat, facebook

I'm having trouble with a site im currently working on.

We are trying to make facebook connect comments widget. The widget loads every time we make a new request that responds with a 200 OK status. But when it returns with a 304 Not Modified the widget wont load.

It all points out to a caching issue. I tryed changin the context.xml

```
<Context cachingAllowed="false">
```

This did not seem to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 16):

> *This did not seem to work. Any tips?*

The `cachingAllowed` attribute *actually* configures the server-side caching, not the client-side caching as you seem to expect.

Client-side caching is to be done with appropriate response headers. To entirely disable client-side caching on the particular resources, you need to create a `Filter` which listens on the desired `url-pattern` and has at least the following lines inside the `doFilter()` method:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

The `response` is here by the way the [`HttpServletResponse`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) which is been casted back from the 2nd `ServletResponse` argument of the `doFilter()` method.

Don't forget to clear the client-side cache (thus, inside the webbrowser config) before testing this all :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is at the client browser caching it, try appending a random number to your request. like `__rnd__= Math.random()`